# Trying to remove specific characters from a string C++

Tags: c++

i need help with removing some non-alphabetical characters from strings. I've been using a method where you look for `ascii` symbols that dont lay within the a-z and A-Z area. It removes some characters like " ! ", and " ? ", but it dosent remove " " " and " ) " from the end of words.

```
for(j=0;j<word.size();j++){
     if(word[j]<'A' || word[j]>'Z'
        word[j]<'a' || word[j]>'z'){
        word.erase(j,1);
        j--;
        wordsave.push_back(word)}}
```

This code gets data from a textfile, with a random story in it, it saves the word that is modified to a `vector` called "wordsave". `word` is just the string, saving the word from the file temporarily.
The word goes through the whole program because at the end of the program i have a `cout` that proves that it went through the program.
What could be the problem behind this code, that makes it skip out on removing some characters?

Comment: You might want to consider using `isalpha` to determine whether a character is alphabetic. To copy things that fit some criteria, I'd consider using `std::copy_if`.

Comment: My answer takes a very different approach, but to fix your code "as-is", you'd be better off doing your check on only a lower-case or upper-case letter. I recommend looking at an ASCII table and trying to understand why. The library `<cctype>` contains functions for these conversions as well as the the `isalpha` function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method using a well-established idiom, aptly called the erase/remove idiom. It's more efficient than multiple random erases. It takes advantage of a few Standard Library functions, and doesn't require an unnecessary copy.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string str("a678b@#$c");
  std::cout << str << '\n';

  str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
                           [](char c) { return !std::isalpha(c); }),
            str.end());
  std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
a678b@#$c
abc
```

You could pull this code out into its own function, and iterate over your vector, calling the function for each element.